# "Creerle" vs "Creerla"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

Tengo una duda respecto al uso de "creerle" o "creerla". He escrito algo así:

> -- Quiero pedirte disculpas.
>    Recordando la noche anterior, a Martín le costó creerle.

Una persona que posiblemente tenga un dominio del idioma mucho mejor que el mío me ha sugerido cambiar "creerle" por "creerla". Sin embargo me suena muy poco natural, aunque es posible que la causa sea que mi español nativo es latinoamericano y el suyo es de España.

¿Es una de las dos formas claramente correcta, o es cuestión de preferencia o dialecto?

Comment: Nunca he escuchado creerla

Answer (score 5):

Es cuestión de laísmo, leísmo (que también hay mucho en España) y loísmo.

Etimológicamente, sin duda el pronombre de acusativo femenino con función de complemento directo es *la* y el masculino es *lo*, mientras *le* es un pronombre de dativo (del latín *illi*) que desempeña la función de complemento indirecto, independientemente del género del sustantivo al que se refiere el pronombre, aunque en  oraciones impersonales se ha usado el dativo como complemento directo ("Se le cree desaparecido") desde los orígenes del castellano.

Quizás por ello, para complicar más las cosas, desde desde los primeros textos medievales castellanos se comenzó a emplear *le* también como acusativo masculino de persona y *lo* para el acusativo masculino de cosa, aunque esto no caló mucho en Andalucía, y por tanto, tampoco se extendió mucho por América, donde el leísmo puede ser más  bien por influencia de otras lenguas y aplicado de formas menos aceptadas.

Para terminar de enredarlo todo, no siempre está claro cuando un verbo requiere un pronombre como CD o CI. Los verbos llamados de «afección psíquica» como *afectar* o *asustar* y algunos otros admiten tanto el uso de los pronombres acusativos como dativos. En esto casos la elección depende de que el sujeto sea animado y el agente de la acción,en cuyo caso el complemento verbal suele considerarse directo y se  emplea el acusativo, o bien el si sujeto es inanimado o es una oración, que no puede ser agente directos de la acción, entonces el complemento se considera indirecto y se usan el dativo, aunque no siempre es así porque pueden intervenir otros factores.

Así, si asimilamos *creer* a un «verbo de percepción» o de «afección psíquica» donde la acción proviene de una persona (las cosas no piden disculpas), sería más adecuado el acusativo, pero no se sabe a quién se refiere el pronombre en el ejemplo. Por tanto;

Si cree a Juan debería ser *creerlo*, pero también sería aceptable **creerle** (y quizás considerada más culta en España).

Si cree a María, debería ser *creerla*.

Pero no está clara la premisa (que *creer* e sea un verbo de afección psíquica como *asustar*, ni de percepción como *ver*, ni que sea descabellado usar el dativo en este caso), sobre todo sí María impone mucho respeto, porque entonces entre en juego el generalizado y aceptado (según la RAE) «leísmo de cortesía». Consideren que dicen en la consulta de un médico:

> Me lo dijo la doctora María, pero me cuesta creerle.
>
> Me lo dijo mi amiga María, pero me cuesta creerla.

Muchos usarían siempre *creerla* o *creerle* en ambos casos, pero muy raramente emplearían ambas palabras al contrario, simplemente porque el consejo médico de una doctora (aunque no nos convenciera) generalmente merece mayor consideración que el consejo médico de la vecina del 4ºB. Pero  un criterio basado en la cortesía puede ser muy laxo...

Conclusión: En mi opinión, ambos usos son aceptables.

Comment: Muy interesante tu respuesta. Sin embargo, creerlo o creerla (a alguien) me suena muy mal y no recuerdo haberlo escuchado nunca (y no soy de una zona leísta).

Answer (score 1):

> No lo creo = No crees algo que se dijo o fue mencionado.
>
> No le creo (a ella/a él /a usted) / No te creo (a ti) = No creo lo que dice una persona.

Answer (score 0):

Como la duda es entre creerle o creerla supongo que estas refiriéndote a una persona.

> Recordando la noche anterior, a Martín le costó creer (a María/a Juan)

También podría ser sobre algo.

> Recordando la noche anterior, a Martín le costo creer (la noticia)

Es otro caso de leísmo y ambas son aceptadas "creerle/creerla", aunque me decanto por "creerla/creerlo".

Que es el leismo? El uso de las formas de complemento indirecto `le, les` en lugar de las de complemento directo `lo, los` (para el masculino o neutro) y `la, las` (para el femenino), como en le mataron, les contrataron.

Creer es un verbo transitivo y "a Maria / a Juan" es el complemento directo.

Tienes una tabla en la RAE sobre el uso de [pronombres personales átonos](http://www.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF).

Donde aparece:

- 3ª pers.singular para el complemento directo

  - masculino : lo ,también le(leísmo)
  - femenino : la

Viendo la tabla y como ya menciona Fran si la acción recae a María será `creerla` , en caso de ser Juan `creerlo` o `creerle`(leísmo).

En el `Manual De La Nueva Gramática De La Lengua Española` se puede ver:

> La valoración del leísmo está en función de las alternancias entre
>   dativo y acusativo. En efecto, unos hablantes construyen ciertos verbos (notablemente,
>   ayudar, creer, escuchar y obedecer, pero no solo estos) **con objeto directo,
>   mientras que otros lo hacen con objeto indirecto. Los primeros perciben como leístas
>   expresiones como ayudarles o creerles, que resultan naturales para los segundos**. Las
>   diferencias a las que dan lugar estos verbos, algunos de los cuales ya admitían dativo
>   en latín, suelen estar sujetas a variación geográfica. Por ejemplo, en la mayor parte de
>   los países americanos se construye **creer** con complemento indirecto de persona
>   (creer a María > creerle), pero con complemento directo de cosa (creer una historia
>   creerla): ¿O sea que tú le crees a la vieja? —le preguntó Paloma—. ¿Tú sí le crees?
>   (Bayly, Días).

Como no leísta hago uso del objeto directo. Como eres hispanohablante (ggambet) depende de la persona a quien envíes el mensaje le puede parecer más natural una forma u otra.

Ahora, si me dieran a escoger haría uso del no leísmo que es mayoría en la península, de hecho:

> El leísmo es un rasgo característico de los dialectos del centro de la península Ibérica, a los que la Real Academia Española considera actualmente vulgares. El dictamen académico se ha moderado recientemente, y **se considera aceptable** la forma leísta exclusivamente cuando el complemento directo de la acción es una persona de sexo masculino.

[Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo)

El leísmo es una excepción, aceptado y usado sobretodo en el habla, pero en la escritura me ceñiría a la norma.
Si es masculino creerlo, si es femenino creerla.

Comment: Obviamente, coincido en todo, salvo en incluir al leísmo de persona del dialecto castellano-leonés  como "vulgar", ya que proviene de la Edad Media y según la RAE, "Debido a su extensión **entre hablantes cultos y escritores de prestigio**, se admite el uso de le en lugar de lo en función de complemento directo cuando el referente es una persona de sexo masculino". Y por otro lado, la RAE, contradiciendo lo anterior, admite el leísmo de cortesía también para el sexo femenino, fórmula que se emplea precisamente cuando intentamos evitar un lenguaje vulgar.

Comment: Como apoyo de mi comentario anterior, un extracto de lo que dice la RAE: "**El leísmo no se admite de ningún modo en la norma culta cuando el referente es inanimado** [...] Y tampoco se admite, en general, cuando el referente es una mujer [...] **aunque existen algunos casos en que el leísmo femenino de persona no se considera incorrecto**.

Comment: Como comentas la RAE al final cedió debido al uso entre cultos y escritores de prestigio, pero si estos hubieran seguido la norma no habría sucedido, así pues la aceptación surge de un uso incorrecto de la gramática. Leismo,RAE **Todos estos fenómenos parecen deberse al nacimiento, en época temprana de la evolución del castellano [...] a diferencia de lo que ocurría en latín**. Solo hay que ver la definicón que otorga al leísmo **Es el uso impropio de le(s)**, hay un [articulo acerca del uso](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/el-leismo-una-incorreccion-gramatical-5039/)

Comment: A mi modo de entender es problemática para los nuevos estudiantes como se comenta en [Cuaderno Cervantes](http://www.cuadernoscervantes.com/art_34_lalelo.html) **La presencia de fenómenos como el laísmo y el leísmo en toda la zona centro de la península puede hacer que el estudiante extranjero realice un aprendizaje defectuoso de la lengua española, ya que en este ámbito geográfico se da un sistema pronominal que provoca el error al usar los pronombres átonos**. Si un estudiante adopta el leísmo puede ser corregido en algunas zonas, si adopta el sistema etimológico es irrefutable.

Comment: En [palabras de la RAE](http://www.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=DRC2Ny6YAD6yEoSWaX)
 : "El panorama [del leísmo], sin embargo, dista mucho de ser sencillo". No hay un norma clara y sencilla en este caso. El enlace lo explica suficientemente. Si lo simplificamos tomando como único referente la lógica gramática latina, entonces habría que concluir que todo el español es pura incorección.